# How to compare multiple text files and get all the parts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm processing a lot of captions which are written in a similar pattern.

Usually they look like this:

> "Name Person, Location and Event describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

> "Name OtherPerson, Location and Event describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

> "Name YetOtherPerson, Location and Event describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

> "Name Person, OtherLocation and OtherEvent describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

> "Name OtherPerson, OtherLocation and OtherEvent describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

> "Name YetOtherPerson, OtherLocation and OtherEvent describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"

In one set the caption often only differs by the name of the person at the start.

What would be the most conveniet way to take a thousand of these strings and get all their parts for further processing?

In an earlier script I compared individual files like this:

```
def common_str(a,b):
    """ compare two strings and return biggest common text """
    match = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).find_longest_match(0,len(a),0,len(b))
    return a[match.a:match.a + match.size]
```

But now I wonder if there is a more straightforward way, possibly some well used library?

As an output I'm looking for something like:

File A,B,C share the common str ", Location and Event describtion, xx.xx.xxxx Date"" and then their individual name strings.

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If the lines have all the same fields, and you don't want to get database-y, I would learn some of: zip, set() and the Counter class in the collections module.  But learning to do things with pandas module may pay off in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not the same. I'm sorry, but I oversimplified the samples. These captions are hand written and roughly follow that order. However the common part among strings is copy pasted and exactly the same. Hence I'm looking for a way to get the components.

Comment: I think I see now:  You are trying to identify longest substring matches within a bunch of lines.  I don't think I can help there, but I'll be following this question for sure.